# ManyToMany Hibernate erro

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Olá, tenho uma relacionamento `@ManyToMany` bidirecional entre a classe `Pessoa` e `Endereço`, onde para essas, tenho as tabelas no banco para pessoa, endereço e a tabela para o relacionamento entre elas, a `rel_pes_endereco`.

Ocorre que quando faço a consulta no HQL para testar o relacionamento das classes, fazendo o select da classe Pessoa apresenta o seguinte erro.

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: model.Endereco.pessoas[model.Pessoa]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1134)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:793)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:728)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
```

As classes foram declaradas no cfg.xml

```xml
<mapping class="model.Endereco"/>
<mapping class="model.Pessoa"/>
```

As anotações estão da seguinte forma:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_pessoa")
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_pes")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Endereco.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "rel_pes_endereco",  
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_pes") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_endereco") } )
    private List<Endereco> enderecos;


    //Get Set
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_endereco")
public class Endereco implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_endereco")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "enderecos", targetEntity = Pessoa.class)
    private List<Pessoa> pessoas;  

    //Get e Set
}
```

Comecei a usar a ferramenta recentemente, olhei alguns problemas relacionados e a documentação e fui criando conforme, fiz este mesmo mapeamento de diversas outras formas, porém sempre obtenho a mesma mensagem.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você esta usando @Entity de qual pacote? Ver se esta no pacote javax.persistence.Entity

Comment: Sim, nas duas classes eu só estou usando o pacote javax.persistence.

Comment: Você declarou hashCode(), equals() e toString(), nas classes Pessoa e Endereco? Faz um teste em List<Pessoa> pessoas, somente com mappedBy = "enderecos" e ver o que acontece

Comment: Só não tinha colocado o toString(). 

Deixei no List<Pessoa> da classe "Endereco" somente com  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "enderecos"), porem o erro persistiu.

Comment: Mais uma tentativa, rs... instancia pessoas da seguinte forma: private List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

Comment: Coloquei o ArrayList<Pessoa>(), e depois tentei com ArrayList<Endereco>() também, porem o erro continuou o mesmo, tenso kk

Comment: Tenso mesmo, rs. Voce instanciou as duas variáveis, certo? Observei mais uma coisa, você esta mapeando class="model.Endereco", a sua estrutura de pastas esta java -> model? Se não for esse o caso tentaria usar em vez de @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Endereco.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) dessa forma @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL).

Comment: @LucasNegrerio Como você está usando anotações nas suas classes, o arquivo `cfg.xml` não é necessário. Remova esse arquivo do seu projeto e tente rodar a aplicação novamente para ver se o erro persiste. Além disso, qual versão do Hibernate você está utilizando?

Comment: @FelipeMarinho  Estou usando a versão 4.3.x.
Eu fiz o teste, tirei o cfg.xml, mas começou a apontar erro em outras partes do projeto. Acredito que o hibernate usa as configurações desse arquivo no momento de iniciar.

Comment: @LucasNegrerio Você disse que a exceção ocorre quando você usa *HQL* , talvez o problema esteja nele. Edite sua pergunta e o adicione.

Comment: Olá @FelipeMarinho, fiz uma um teste fora do HQL, criei uma pagina  e um bean e quando tento instanciar a classes Pessoa ou Endereço, ou qualquer uma das classes envolvidas com essas, também apresenta a mesma mensagem de erro que no HQL. Já não sei mais como testar ou o que verificar, os importes JPA, a tabela do banco, mapeamento, unica coisa que não fiz, foi criar um model pra fazer o relacionamento delas, assim como entidade relacional de ManyToMany, porem não acho viável com essa ferramenta.

Comment: @LucasNegrerio Eu fiz um teste com as classes que você colocou aqui (sem o arquivo cfg.xml) e funcionou normalmente. Consegui inserir e buscar as entidades no banco. O que você pode fazer é criar um novo projeto e ir adicionando as classes aos poucos e ir testando para tentar encontrar o erro. Se possível, teste com uma versão mais recente do *Hibernate*. Além disso, verifique se a classe `Pessoa` e `Endereco` estão no pacote model.

Comment: O problema com o ManyToMany deve estar no HQL do cfg.xml que estava usando de teste mesmo. Também mudei no banco, na tabela que faz o Join das entitys, um dos campos Id estava como unique. 
Eu cheguei a criar um novo projeto e refiz, o HQL continuou apontando o erro, porem no na pagina que fiz como teste, fez os insert no banco certinho. 
Obrigado aí pessoal!

Comment: Por fim, nas anotações a unica coisa que mudei foi o new ArrayList<> que adicionei, pois para pegar os endereços  e setar um novo na pessoa estava ocorrendo erro.

    private List<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<Endereco>();
    private List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();